# How to read A.D. and B.C.?

Tags: abbreviations, reading

I know they refer to Before Christ and Anno Domini, but I'm not sure if I should read Before Christ or just "B, C"(the pronunciation of letters).

Comment: I think "B C" (letters) is usual. Same as with "am" and "pm" in times.

Comment: Just say the letters for both: BC and AD. As for reading, you can say the letters or what they stand for.

Comment: @Lambie: I know that strictly speaking the "secular" version is **BCE**, not **BC**. But just because someone else *wrote* BC doesn't mean a fastidious person reading that text out loud must say ***Before Christ*** rather than ***Before Common Era***, if he would prefer the latter for his *own* text.

Comment: @FumbleFinger5s BCE is not BC; those are different. If you want to point out the difference fine but please do not tell me one can read BC as BCE.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, you COULD read "BC" as "Before Common Era" if you have a strong objection to referring to Christ. But then you would be imposing your own interpretation on the text. Like if a newspaper story read, "Senator Jones accepted a bribe from ...", and Senator Jones is from my preferred political party and I don't believe he would do such a thing, I COULD read it, "Senator Jones is alleged to have accepted a bribe from ..." But that's not what the text says, that's inserting my own interpretation.

Comment: @Jay: There's a world of difference between baldly stating something as a fact, and reporting that *someone else* has made such a statement. But secularists and Christians all live by the same calendar today,..  [Bottom line:](https://earthsky.org/human-world/definition-common-era-bce-ce-bc-ad/) *CE (Common Era) and BCE (Before Common Era) **mean the same thing** as anno Domini (AD) and before Christ (BC).*

Comment: @Lambie, what is the difference between BC and BCE? As far as I know they mean the same thing.

Comment: @prl The difference is that the former is an abbreviation of Before Christ and the latter is an abbreviation of Before Common Era.  The two may be describing the same thing, but that kinda just makes them synonyms.  You're free to use whichever you want in your own text, but you'd be paraphrasing if you decided to swap them out in a quote.

Comment: @pri Yes, they do but that was *not* the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always just say the letters "BC" and "AD".

More people know what "AD" means than what "Anno Domini" means.

Comment: It used to be common for a male Brit with a certain level of education to ruefully answer 'anno domini, old chap' if a pal said something like 'Why don't you go to rock concerts any more?'

Comment: The way I was taught Latin at school, I'd say 'domini' differently from the way people seem to say it  in the phrase 'Anno Domini'.

Comment: Yes, to clarify, the former sounds like *bee sea* (an ocean of honey-producing insects) and the latter rhymes with *shady* (though the stress is on the second syllable) and not *shad*.

Comment: Straight Latin would say the -ini like in bikini,, whereas in the AD thing it is like in-eye.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey historically, Medieval and Ecclesiastical Latin would be pronounced with the same pronunciation rules as the speaker's native language. In the 20th century, this largely shifted to a Italianate pronunciation. However, for stock phrases in English, the prior pronunciations tend to be maintained (e.g., "et cetera" is pronounced /ɛt 'sɛtəɹə/ and not /et 'tʃetera/ or /et 'ketera/)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey although interestingly enough, for the coronation of King Charles III, I noticed that they used the English pronunciation in at least the clips I saw. I'm not sure if the Anglican Church as a whole still uses English pronunciation rules for Latin, but it *appeared* at least they use English pronunciation for solemn high liturgies (such as a coronation). However, I imagine there's very little if any Latin for most ordinary liturgies (although I am neither English nor Anglican so I'm not confident, but I'd be surprised)